# application.xml updated by maven update project

Tags: maven, application.xml

Good morning all.

Quick question: when I do a "maven update project" my application.xml file is updated.

I have abc-ear/META-INF/application.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <description>Application abc construite avec le framework Sphinx.</description>
  <display-name>def</display-name>
  <module id="WebModule_1301067741013">
    <web>
        <web-uri>def-web.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>def</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module id="WebModule_1306335826653">
    <web>
        <web-uri>ghi-web.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>jkl_bo</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module id="WebModule_1330011848203">
    <web>
        <web-uri>mno-web.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>mno_bp</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

And my abc-ear/src/dev/application/META-INF/application.xml contains this after "maven update projects" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
    <display-name>abc-ear</display-name>
</application>
```

I'm using maven-ear-plugin :

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <fileNameMapping>full</fileNameMapping> -->
                <!-- <defaultLibBundleDir>.</defaultLibBundleDir> -->
                <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                <applicationXml>${basedir}/META-INF/application.xml</applicationXml>
                <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Date>
                        <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                        <!-- <Baseline>${baseline.number}</Baseline> -->
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <!-- On doit faire en sorte que le numero de version du war soit retiré 
                    sinon, chaque sous version va demander de reconfigurer le serveur -->
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>abc-web</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/abc</contextRoot> <!-- Voir application XML -->
                        <bundleFileName>abc-web.war</bundleFileName>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>def-web</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/ghi_bo</contextRoot> <!-- Voir application XML -->
                        <bundleFileName>def-web.war</bundleFileName>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ghi-web</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/ghi_bp</contextRoot> <!-- Voir application XML -->
                        <bundleFileName>ghi-web.war</bundleFileName>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
                 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Before mvn clean install, I need to
git checkout application.xml
If i don't do it, it doesn't work.

Can you tell me why ?

maven version : apache-maven-3.0.4

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what your question is? Is the application.xml hand made? Do you use maven-ear-plugin? Are you really using Maven 3.0.4? (Upgrade to the most recent version asap)...

Comment: Yes, I'm using maven-ear-plugin. I edit my post. I can't upgrade the version.